# Dynamics: Continuity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras

*Disclaimer: This is a record of results.*

Given a C*-algebra $\mathcal{A}\subseteq\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$.

Consider a Hamiltonian dynamics:
$$H:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{H}:\quad\tau^t[A]:=e^{itH}Ae^{-itH}$$

Clearly, for bounded Hamiltonians:
$$H\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}):\quad\tau^t[A]\stackrel{t\to0}{\to}A$$

Trivially, it holds also for:
$$\mathcal{A}=\mathbb{C}:\quad\tau^t[\lambda1]\stackrel{t\to0}{\to}\lambda1$$

> What nontrivial examples are there:
>   $$\mathcal{A}\neq\mathbb{C}:\quad\tau^t[A]\stackrel{t\to0}{\to}A\quad(H\notin\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}))$$

Comment: Does there exist a "bounded Hamiltonian?"

Comment: There is a general reason for that, which makes "bounded Hamiltonian" a contradiction in terms. An oxymoron.

Comment: @T.A.E.: In general, it is unbounded. Clearly the time evolution of states will be uniformly continuous iff the Hamiltonian is bounded. However, the dynamics of observables may be strongly continuous though the Hamiltonian is unbounded. So boundedness is **not necessary**.

Comment: Operator continuity of a semigroup implies bounded generator.

Comment: @T.A.E.: You mean that uniform continuity implies bounded generator. But I mean strong continuity. The problem is that for Hamiltonian dynamics usually $\tau^t[A]=e^{itH}Ae^{-itH}\nrightarrow A$ but only $\tau^t[A]\varphi=e^{itH}Ae^{-itH}\varphi\nrightarrow A\varphi$

Comment: So you need to get in the habit of stating the topology you're using. Nothing is obvious from you've written.

Comment: And I still strongly object to a "bounded Hamiltonian." That is an oxymoron.

Comment: Yes but here it might be rather more confusing as in words it is the continuity of the semigroup in the strong operator topology on the Banach space of bounded operators of bounded operators over the Hilbert space :)

Comment: You could say "for a bounded selfadjoint operator H, one has" without suggesting that there exists a bounded Hamiltonian.

Comment: @T.A.E.: But what if I want an unbounded "Hamiltonian"?

Comment: @T.A.E.: My idea so far was $H:\mathcal{D}\to\mathcal{H}$ hints on unbounded Hamiltonian while $H\in\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ clearly adresses bounded Hamiltonians.

Comment: You don't have a real choice about having an unbounded Hamiltonian for a physical system. Do you? There is baggage that comes with the name Hamiltonian. If you want to just discuss Math, then I suggest you drop the name so that others won't be confused, and Math folks will better understand, too. I've never heard of a bounded Hamiltonian; so I would assume unbounded.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Depends on the context: Fermions with arbitrary large energies so unbounded Hamiltonians. But also confined systems so bounded Hamiltonians. In principle my setting is small system plus large reservoirs so both can appear.

Comment: @T.A.E.: Perfect, that is also my assumption: Unbounded Hamiltonian!

Comment: By the way, what values are involved in your "bounded Hamiltonian," and what are the relations between those variables? For example, what are the commutation relations?

Comment: Reminder: No bounded Hamiltonian a priori! Well: $\|\mathcal{W}(H)\|=\|\sigma(H)\|=\|H\|(=\infty)$ In general, no commutation relations! *(I don't have a specific Hamiltonian only a usual scenario, System & Reservoirs.)*

Comment: @T.A.E.: See, I do not invoke bounded Hamiltonians. *(I just mentioned them hypothetically.)*

Comment: @T.A.E.: Besides, are you familiar with the Landauer Büttiker formula?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given the Fock space $\mathcal{F}(\mathcal{h})$.

Consider the second quantization:
$$\Gamma(e^{ith})=e^{it\mathrm{d}\Gamma(h)}$$

It acts continuous on the CAR-algebra:
$$\quad\tau^t[a(\eta)]=a(e^{ith}\eta)\stackrel{t\to0}{\to}a(\eta)$$
*(Remember that this won't work for the Weyl algebra.)*